# How to reuse a method, but adding more features to the second one?

Tags: java, reusability, code-reuse

I have a method `addUser()` in Class `Register` that works as a regular form, asking the user of the system things like "*firstName*", "*lastName*", "*username*", and "*password*".

```
class Register {
  void addUser() {
    try {
      System.out.print("First Name:\n> ");
      String firstName = userInput.nextLine();
      (...)
  }
}
```

**Only once** the user is registered and logged in, they can add new customers using a method in the Class `Customer`, that performs just as `addUser()`, but adding more fields, like "*address*" and "*email*".

```
class Customer {

/*At the moment I'm redoing all over again just because it works.
and because I didn't know how to implement in any other way.*/

  void addCustomer() {
    try {
      System.out.print("First Name:\n> ");
      String firstName = userInput.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Address:\n> ");
      String address = userInput.nextLine();
      (...)
```

How can I reuse the `addUser()` method in the `Customer` class using the fact that the user is logged in as a condition? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: inheritance, extend the class by another, and add the additional instructions in the child class

Comment: a little sidenote: By initializing the variables in the try blocks, you make them inaccessible from outside the try block/scope. What you probably want, is initializing the variables for the whole class `Customer` and then setting them in the try block. Won't fix your problem - but I just noticed that

Comment: That's not how OOP is supposed to work. A User and a Customer are two different Concepts in your Domain. The fact that you need to ask a set of information from the user in various places should lead you to a class that does just that (with different "config").

Comment: I did try inheritance, but I had problems while trying to access, but I didn't realise that it was because of the try/catch, it says a lot. Thanks for that. Regarding whether I should carry on with that, it's a fair point. I just thought about applying the concept of code reusability here.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd suggest you move the addUser method out of both Register and Customer - that way you have some guarantee that the method is not tied to any particular use case and thus will be reusable.

Then you're going to need to create mechanism for both calling contexts (Customer and Register) to interface with the addUser method. For this you could use some kind of data object which they exchange, and then once they get it back they pull out the data they want, or you can let both them implement an interface that the addUser method can be passed with which it will and back what it captures.

I don't feel using inheritance is a good enabler of reuse in this case. Inheritance is something which must be done carefully as it can also increase dependencies. It is important to adhere to the idea that when using inheritance the 2 types being inheritance should actually have some inheritance relationship - I don't think this is the case here.

So then the Register user can call this addUser method and the Customer class can call this addUser method and then add the extra fields it includes.

Comment: Thank you, I'll reconsider a different approach based on that. This actually helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static boolean value set to false (e.g: isLoggedIn). If the user logs in successfully, change it to true. Then call this method in the Customer class (create Register object) only if the isLoggedIn variable equals true

Comment: because you want code that can only be used by one person at the time?

Comment: No, this is just a check if the user is logged in. And inheritance as stated in a comment above may also offer a solution for this.

Comment: A boolean can only tell if **_a_** user is logged in or not. Inheritance doesn't help here at all. OP's code needs to be refactored beyond a simple "make a child class".

Comment: It's true. I did try with static boolean, but no success. My problem with inheritance was the implementation of the method. How can I add more instructions to the inherited method?

Answer (score 0):

I'll rephrase your question as "How can I make my code less repetitive and easier to maintain through reuse?"

The solution in that case is to create a *reusable function* that takes care of the repeated task of printing a prompt and reading in from the keyboard:

```
public class Console {

  public static String prompt(String field) {
    System.out.print(field + ":\n> ");
    return userInput.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Then you can simplify your other functions:

```
void addUser(){
  try {
    String firstName = Console.prompt("First Name");
    (...)
  }
}

void addCustomer(){
  try {
    String firstName = Console.prompt("First Name");
    String address = Console.prompt("Address");
    (...)
  }
}
```

Other forms of reuse are object composition and inheritance, but I feel that they are not necessary based on the example code that you gave.